# -webkit color stop acting weird

Tags: html, css, webkit

My HTML document contains `#victimDiv` thats `background image` property is set to:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(-75deg, black 10px, #4AC0F2);
```

After I load `#victimDiv` with ajax call and its height prolongs, gradient gets longer as its length is defined in percentage instead being fixed in pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood syntax meaning:
pixels or percentage after color means that color starts from there not ends. Kind of a weird name `color stop`???
Anyway right syntax for what I wanted to achieve is:

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(-75deg, black, #4AC0F2 10px);
```

Good night, and good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you apply css length parameters on an element when the element is not already in the DOM. this is not possible... try to do it with the css embedded in the respective html tag.

Comment: `#victimDiv` is in the DOM, it is just that its content is changing making it longer.